# Create alias Git Bash Windows 10

Tags: git, bash

How to create alias for Git Bash on Windows 10? I need to create an alias of the long path to my project folder so I don't have to type it again and again whenever I open bash.
I've searched for answers and tried several "correct answers" but none has worked for me so far.

They include:
create a `.bashrc` or some people suggest `.bashrc.` (after creating this file, I cannot do anything with it. windows says

> Could not find this item This is no longer located in C:\.
>   Verify the item's location and try again.

)
`echo alias='<path>' > .bashrc` (iI've also tried >>)

I can edit the file `.bashrc` and put aliases in there but none of them works.
I've tried editing the `.gitconfig` file in my home folder [alias] =''

Same result whenever I type: `cd <alias name>`:

> No such file or directory

All I need to do is to type: cd  and it will lead me to ~///...

Comment: A bash alias is an alias to a command, you can't use this as parameters to commands. You most likely want to set an environment variable, or just create an alias to the whole cd command with the right path.

Comment: an alias is a command, it won't work with a path. Try `alias cdProject=cd /your/long/project/path`. Also run and test it a first time before putting it in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Note that when you run _anything_ `>~/.bashrc`, you're deleting everything that _used to be_ in your `.bashrc`; so you might add a new alias, but when you do that you're deleting all the old aliases.

Comment: And aliases in bash only match against the _command name itself_, not arguments, so `cd <alias_name>` is not expected to work at all in the first place.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open the bash terminal
2. cd ~
3. vi .bashrc
4. press `i` to go edit mode and update it with you alias command.
5. press `Esc` and press `:wq`(save and exit)
6. now close and reopen the bash terminal
7. check the alias command.

if this didn't work create the `.bash_profile` in the same way and add the line

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

Comment: to elaborate on #4, syntax is like this: `alias [alias name]="[your command]"`

Answer (score 5):

You can also open and edit the file `aliases.sh` that you find in the installation path of Git.

> `C:\path where you installed Git\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh`

Open it with VS Code or Notepad++ and add a line like:

```
alias MyProjectName='C:/<installation_path_of_your project>/'
```

and save.

Close and reopen Git Bash.

Now if you type: `MyProjectName` in Bash, it should automatically bring you to the desired path.

If it doesn't work try with

```
cd MyProjectName
```

Comment: This is simply wrong. `alias MyProjectName='cd /cygdrive/c/YourProject/...'` might work', but you certainly can't leave out the `cd`, nor can you use the alias name in the position of the directory name (in bash) and expect it to be honored when it's an argument rather than a command as such.

Comment: The edited question is still not including the `cd` _within the alias_, and is still telling the user to run `cd` as the primary command, rather than running _the alias itself_.